# Android registerForActivityResult launch never prompting for Permissions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I am trying to simply prompt for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in a hello world targetSdk 28 Android app running on a Android 12 Pixel 5.

The whole project is here:
https://github.com/paulpv/AndroidPermissionsTest

The main code meat is:
build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.permissionstest"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest ...>

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28"
        />

    <application
        ...
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
    private var runAfterRequestWriteExternalStoragePermissions: (() -> Unit)? = null
    private val writeExternalStoragePermissionsRequired =
        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    private val requestWriteExternalStoragePermissions =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
            val runAfter = runAfterRequestWriteExternalStoragePermissions
            runAfterRequestWriteExternalStoragePermissions = null
            if (permissions.containsValue(false)) return@registerForActivityResult
            runAfter?.invoke()
        }

    private fun requestWriteExternalStoragePermissions(runAfter: () -> Unit) {
        Log.i(TAG, "+requestWriteExternalStoragePermissions(...)")
        writeExternalStoragePermissionsRequired.forEach {
            val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, it)
            if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                runAfterRequestWriteExternalStoragePermissions = runAfter
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(it)) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder(this).apply {
                        setTitle("Permission(s) Required")
                        setMessage("Please allow the required permission(s)")
                        setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
                            requestWriteExternalStoragePermissions.launch(
                                writeExternalStoragePermissionsRequired
                            )
                        }
                        setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    }.show()
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "requestWriteExternalStoragePermissions: requestWriteExternalStoragePermissions.launch($writeExternalStoragePermissionsRequired)")
requestWriteExternalStoragePermissions.launch(writeExternalStoragePermissionsRequired)
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "-requestWriteExternalStoragePermissions(...)")
                return
            }
        }
        runAfter()
        Log.i(TAG, "-requestWriteExternalStoragePermissions(...)")
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.v(TAG, "+onCreate(...)")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //...
        requestWriteExternalStoragePermissions {
            Log.i(TAG, "Huzzah!")
        }
        Log.v(TAG, "-onCreate(...)")
    }
```

The log shows onCreate followed by onStart, then onResume, then onPause, then onResume:

```
2022-06-14 22:42:47.956 28831-28831/com.example.permissionstest V/MainActivity: +onCreate(...)
2022-06-14 22:42:48.416 28831-28831/com.example.permissionstest I/MainActivity: +requestWriteExternalStoragePermissions(...)
2022-06-14 22:42:48.419 28831-28831/com.example.permissionstest I/MainActivity: requestWriteExternalStoragePermissions: requestWriteExternalStoragePermissions.launch([Ljava.lang.String;@7baaa6)
2022-06-14 22:42:48.430 28831-28831/com.example.permissionstest I/MainActivity: -requestWriteExternalStoragePermissions(...)
2022-06-14 22:42:48.430 28831-28831/com.example.permissionstest V/MainActivity: -onCreate(...)
2022-06-14 22:42:48.446 28831-28831/com.example.permissionstest V/MainActivity: +onStart()
2022-06-14 22:42:48.463 28831-28831/com.example.permissionstest V/MainActivity: -onStart()
2022-06-14 22:42:48.469 28831-28831/com.example.permissionstest V/MainActivity: +onResume()
2022-06-14 22:42:48.470 28831-28831/com.example.permissionstest V/MainActivity: -onResume()
2022-06-14 22:42:48.514 28831-28831/com.example.permissionstest V/MainActivity: +onPause()
2022-06-14 22:42:48.521 28831-28831/com.example.permissionstest V/MainActivity: -onPause()
2022-06-14 22:42:48.987 28831-28831/com.example.permissionstest V/MainActivity: +onResume()
2022-06-14 22:42:48.987 28831-28831/com.example.permissionstest V/MainActivity: -onResume()
```

Any idea why my `requestWriteExternalStoragePermissions.launch(...)` isn't launching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From android 12 now you dont need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Instead you will need to implement scoped storage for devices above android 11. Refer https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#permissions-target-11

Comment: The example app has `targetSdk 28`, Android 9, nor is subject to Google Play rules. I would presume that if an app is compiled as `targetSdk 28` then it is not subject to target higher SDK rules, even if it is run on Android 12 (API32). Unless my thinking is flawed...

Comment: There are 2 things I would like to bring to your notice. 1st you have set the maxsdk for external permission to 28 in menifest. So it will not ask permission above sdk 28. 2nd. According to the google docs i shared, this behaviour is irrespective of ypur target sdk but is dependent on the android version the app will be running on.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#permissions-target-any

Comment: Thanks! Android/AOSP has historically not made this elementary to understand. I get the jist of what you are saying and will mark it as the answer until I learn anything differently.